# Baseball Heap Maps in R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, heat

I'm trying to create hitter heat maps that are dependent upon the average value of runs a certain hit is worth, plotted based on physical location of coordinates, ex. so that higher values of an area on the map are red, lower values are blue.

I've researched a bit and can't seem to come up with a solution for this.

EX plot locations + value (X is based on center of plate, to the left is negative, right is positive in meters):

[Plot Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QnWm.png)

For each of these plot points, there is an attached value (i.e some are 0.5, 0.25, 0, -0.5).

Is there a way to plot that buckets these values and averages them out to create a heatmap similar to this: [Heat Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5JIa.jpg)

I don't need it to be continuous like that necessarily, I'm fine with bucketing them. I know how to create the plot with the strike zone built in through ggplot and plot each point individually, but I'm struggling to find a way to aggregate based on nearby plot points and transform that into a heat meap.

My first post here, apologies if I am not up to standard with the amount of detail provided, if there's any more relevant info I can include I'm happy to.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the `ggplot2` library's hexagon bin heatmap. Check out the examples on this page https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_hex.html

Comment: Hi adbmke. Welcome to StackOverflow! Your post could benefit from a bit more detail on what you already tried as well as example data and code. You could read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: I used hexagon bin for pitch frequency, but the issue with that is I believe it's just a counting function? I.E. it doesn't aggregate for each hexagon just counts within it..is there a way to manipulate that function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to base your heatmap on the `mean` of the Value variable, use the `stat_summary_hex()` function.

The data are divided into bins defined by `x` and `y`, and then the values of `z` in each cell is are summarized with fun.

The default "summary" function is `mean(z)`.

The code below makes a heatmap plot using the mean of depth.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, z=depth)) + 
   stat_summary_hex()
```

`fun` argument is the function for summary, the default function can be overridden with any function. For example `max()`.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, z=depth)) + 
   stat_summary_hex(fun = "max")
   #stat_summary_hex(fun = function(a) max(a)) #alternative for complex functions
```

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary.html